# How to trigger automatic indentation on commit in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos, indentation

In Xcode, is it possible to automatically trigger indentation on Objective-C code for a file when committing it?
Does someone know a tool to reindent Objective-C code in bash?

Comment: Why not simply indent it properly while you're editing it??

Comment: maybe because it's a waste of time when you can do it automatically ?

Comment: It's a waste of time (and a major source of bugs) to edit code that is not properly formatted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add something like [uncrustify](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/) to the git pre-commit [hook](http://githooks.com/).